# How to validate number as well as string in one EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to achieve an EditText which validates both below cases.

Case: 1
EditText should only take the value of a certain range. (0-70)

Case: 2
EditText should only take the optional value "Abs" from dialog input & should ignore the number validation which we set in case 1.

How can I make this work in a single EditText using TextWatcher?

Answer (score 0):

In your EditText TextWatcher add this code:

```
 String text = editText.getText().toString();

    int lenght = text.length();
    boolean containtDigit = false;
    boolean containChar;

    // if there are any character metches return true
    containChar = text.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*");

    // check for digits
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) >= '0' && text.charAt(i) <= '9') {
            containtDigit = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (containChar && containtDigit) {
        return editText.setMaxLenght(/*your max length for string*/); // is string 
    } else if (containtDigit && !containChar) { 
           editText.setMaxLenght(20);               
           retutn // is digit and must 20 character
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a **studentMarksEditText** is a input field & to make a **editext** valid between 0 . to full marks and make it accept a string character "Abs" as well.

```
 studentMarksEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("0", maxTheoryMarks)});


  private class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {
            private double min, max;

            InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
                try {

                    this.min = Double.parseDouble(min);
                    this.max = Double.parseDouble(max);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

                try {
                    if (source.equals("Abs")) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        // Remove the string out of destination that is to be replaced
                        String newVal = dest.toString().substring(0, dstart) + dest.toString().substring(dend, dest.toString().length());
                        // Add the new string in
                        newVal = newVal.substring(0, dstart) + source.toString() + newVal.substring(dstart, newVal.length());
                        double input = Double.parseDouble(newVal);
                        if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                            return null;

                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

            }
            return "";

        }

        private boolean isInRange(double a, double b, double c) {
            return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
        }
    }
```